# How to check status of my AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a web application, in which I'm making an AJAX call to fetch some data. The data can vary from a 100 Kb to 1 Mbs. Also, this call take a lot of time, since I need to do a lot of processing at the back-end.

I'm running into 2 basic issues:

1) It takes a lot of time, so I need to show some status of the AJAX call to the end-user, so that they don't get frustrated. I was thinking if there was a way to make an AJAX call after some interval to check the progress of the initial AJAX call, or may be something you can suggest?

2) When the data is received, it sometimes even hangs the browser tab for like a minute or two, because I'm painting the page through JavaScript. Would there be a way to stop or reduce this hanging time?

Any advice would be really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got a way through. I was able to check the progress without actually painting any iFrame. I simply created a session variable and keep on updating its value at the server side. I set a timeout function to trigger every sec, and checked the session variable's value by making an AJAX call. I know it's creating some extra load on the server, but I don't know any other way by now. Any more suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

1. AJAX provides status events on the client side, however in your case i dont think that will hold good as you want to send the progress to the end user, i would rather suggest you to trick it by doing an ajax call using an iframe which will constantly flush the progress from server to the client.
2. If the data is huge and you start painting its obvious that your browser will hang, i would suggest you to refine your painting mechanism to use setTimeout / setInterval, also if you follow step 1 you can start working with the flushed data from the server without waiting for the complete data till end

**EDIT - How to show progress via iframe**

lets say you have main.aspx where you have your whole content and doing an ajax call

You also have a info.aspx which will give you data from the server.

your info.aspx contains 6 steps and you want to inform the user for every single step.

```
//Step 1 - do some thing
Response.Write("<script>progress = '10'; progressText = 'Completed step 1'; ");
Response.Write(" updateProgress(); </script>");
Response.Flush();

//Step 2 - do some thing
Response.Write("<script>progress = '30'; progressText = 'Completed step 2'; ");
Response.Write(" updateProgress(); </script>");
Response.Flush();
```

in the above case we are updating the progress and progressText variable and calling `updateProgress()` javascript, the updateProgress will look like

```
function updateProgress()
{
    //update parent window/container on the progress which will show an visual indicator of the progress
}
```

the updateProgress() function is flushed in the beginning

Comment: Would you be able to provide some example of how to use an iframe to flush the progress? I'm in serious need of a work-through.

Comment: an upvote would help! ... anyways here is what you need to do with iframe, when you want to load some info instead of using tradinional ajax try to load it in a web page ... somewebpage.aspx where in .aspx file or any other which u use(php etc) can constantly push information in a json or some javascript which can be picked by your code on the client side.

Comment: thank you! let me know if the solution works for you, i would have fiddled but it more on the server side.

Comment: So, what I understand is that there may not be a way to inform the user about the progress. This iframe would basically help in loading the content gradually, which may stop the system from hanging. It still doesn't solve my complete problem though. I'll keep on exploring. Thanks.

Comment: not really, the content from the iframe can be used to inform the progress to the user... let me edit my answer to include more details on the progress updation

Comment: if it solved your problem! please dont forget to mark my answer as the right one

Comment: How do I know when the step 1 is completed? I'll be loading all the data in a single AJAX call, so I don't really have my process broken in steps.

Comment: your process should be broken at the code on your server and not on the client, the code which i gave you is on the server and not on client. which programming language you use on the server ?

Comment: I use Java and JSP. I understand what you're trying to say, but not quite sure if that is possible through Struts framework I'm using.

Comment: i am sure it should be possible! why dont you give it a try ?